# ash - case insensitive

Tags: autocomplete, ash

I am using the ash shell (on Busybox) and I want to make the tab completion case insensitive. "cd a" and Tab completes only all directories starting with a but ignore all directories which start with A.

I tried "set completion-ignore-case on" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `libbb/lineedit.c:complete_cmd_dir_file()` in the `busybox-1.26.2` source code archive, there's no such option in `busybox` at the moment, and you need to adjust the sources yourself.